# Calculating loading time of css/js/img sources

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the loading time of one single css/javascript/img url (this one for example http://g2.delfi.lt/scms/?g=delfi-fp.css&1362823940).

I tried pingdom, and it calculated 749ms, i would like to know how they calculate this. This is all the calculations they do (i think):

```
DNS - 443ms
Connect - 589ms
Send - 1ms
Wait - 152ms
Receive - 1ms
Total - 1.19s
```

I dont understand how they got 0.749s from 1.19s. What do they subtract from what?

I tried using curl for calculating the loading time, but it did not give me the results i was expecting for:

```
$src_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $url1) {
        $curl1 = curl_init();   
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); 
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 300); 
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 300);
        curl_exec($curl1); //curl ivykdymas
        $contime1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
        $src_array[] = $contime1;
    }

$gg = (array_sum($src_array));
```

How do i calculate loading time of 1 specific js/css/img source ?

Comment: Are you looking for the load time in a browser or on your server?

Comment: Pingdom calculated time is `Total time` - `DNS time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the calculation.

```
DNS: 443ms
Connect: 589ms + Send: 1ms + Wait: 152ms + Receive: 1ms = 743ms
Total = 1.19s
Grand total = 1.19s - 443ms = 747ms
```